# mpandroidchart: How to set padding beetween axis and grid?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I want to draw a chart, where values of y-axis (on a left) will be inside of chart, but between this axis value and grid (lines) should be a space, so axis value should not overlap grid.

For now numbers fit inside chart, but there is no gap between them and line. How to do this? You can see the current result at a picture

```
                   val values = mutableListOf<Entry>()

                values.add(Entry(1f, 666f))
                values.add(Entry(2f, 1000f))
                values.add(Entry(3f, 333f))
                values.add(Entry(4f, 985f))
                values.add(Entry(5f, 3000f))
                values.add(Entry(6f, 2f))
                values.add(Entry(7f, 50f))

                val lineChart = LineChart(context)
                lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true)
                lineChart.isDragEnabled = true
                lineChart.legend.isEnabled = false
                lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
                lineChart.setDrawBorders(false)
                lineChart.xAxis.setDrawAxisLine(false)
                lineChart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
                lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
                lineChart.axisLeft.setPosition(YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.INSIDE_CHART)
                lineChart.axisLeft.setDrawGridLines(true)
                lineChart.axisLeft.setDrawGridLinesBehindData(false)
                lineChart.axisLeft.setDrawLimitLinesBehindData(false)
                lineChart.xAxis.setDrawGridLines(false)
                lineChart.isHapticFeedbackEnabled = true
                lineChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = object: ValueFormatter() {
                    override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
                        if (value == values.first().x || value == values.last().x) {
                            return value.toString()
                        } else {
                            return ""
                        }
                    }
                }

                val set1 = LineDataSet(values, "DataSet 1")
                set1.setDrawIcons(false)
                set1.color = Color.YELLOW
                set1.lineWidth = 1f
                set1.setDrawValues(false)

                val lineDataSet = LineData(set1)

                lineChart.data = lineDataSet
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no way and that doesn't make sense to do it (because the effect will just like the label set outside the grid line). In you case you should only set the position of labels to `YAxis.YAxisLabelPosition.OUTSIDE_CHART`